# Error in Setup gazebo plugin paths - GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, I am trying to add a controller to my robot, (using plugin). So I am going to follow the tutorials [Mobile Base Control](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.2/control_robot/mobile_base) and [Plugin Hello World](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/2.2/plugins/HelloWorld). But I have three problem:
1 - **/grad/hadi.kazemi/my_plugin/my_plugin.cc:2:21: fatal error: gazebo.hh: No such file or directory** so I add a **/gazebo/** to all include lines and the error vanished.

2 - **error: ‘ConnectWorldUpdateStart’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’** when I try to make, so I delete this line (this line was in the first tutorial).

3 - after removing the make worked well but when I try to run this command: export **GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=`pwd`:$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH** or **export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=${GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH}:~/my_plugin/build/** it gave me this error: **GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH: Undefined variable.** and so when I add my model to the world (using insert) I have: **Error [Plugin.hh:152] Failed to load plugin libmy_plugin.so: libmy_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

how can I handle these errors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5624/error-in-setup-gazebo-plugin-paths---gazebo_plugin_path/) by [Hadi Kazemi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/659/hadi-kazemi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2014-03-12**:
did you source your bashrc after setting the plugin path? you can verify it by running `$ echo $GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH`, and see if the path where the plugin .so is included

**Comment by [Hadi Kazemi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/659/hadi-kazemi/) on 2014-03-13**:
I did not install gazebo in the computer by myself. I am a PhD student and the university tech group installed it for me. I have not a root access and I don't know what is bachrc? I did your command : echo $GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH and the same error: GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH: Undefined variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I solve my problem by adding "setenv `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH` ~/my_plugin/build" to .cshrc

---

Originally posted by [Hadi Kazemi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/659/hadi-kazemi/) with karma: 16 on 2014-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

try this command on top of the cmakeLists.txt,this worked for me

```
find_package(gazebo REQUIRED)
```